# Two 24" monitors with different resolutions

Tags: display, resolution, external-display

I have a HP E**24**li and a dell E**24**14Ht

https://www.cnet.com/products/hp-elitedisplay-e241i-led-monitor-24-smart-buy/specs/
https://www.cnet.com/products/dell-e2414h-led-monitor-24-series/specs/

But they have different native resolutions ie:

- 1920 x 1200 at 60 Hz
- 1920 x 1080 at 60 Hz

One can physically see that that the Dell is shorter, but how can they have the same viewable size when the `X` resolution is the same but the `Y` is different?

Comment: Basically, there is no way to tell your computer the physical size of a monitor, only its dimensions. It cannot compensate for 'size' alone.

Comment: Right so basically my question is since both physical viewable size is the same while the resolution is different; does that mean the the image is more squished on one monitor or am i missing something

Comment: @ctles , do you mean something like letterboxing, where a black band appears on the monitor with more y-pixels?  Some monitors and TVs have Zoom functions like that, which would appear in the On-Screen Display of the monitor itself, if it's available.  I rarely see the feature.  You would also need to tell the OS to send the desired resolution 1920x1080.  In Windows, that's available in Display Settings->Advanced Display Settings->Display adapter properties->List All Modes.

Comment: no there's no letter boxing. Maybe i'm thinking about it the wrong way; however, if they both have the screen display size. and then the same number of X pixels, why would the Y number be different?

Comment: Please be aware that old CRTs didn't have a set number of pixels in either direction... you could feed the CRT arbitrary resolutions and it would display as requested.  Modern LCD and LED flatscreens have a precise number of pixels in each dimension.  If you feed the 1920x1080p monitor a different resolution, at best it will be fuzzy, but it might not display at all.  In OP's case, the two monitors were just manufactured with different aspect ratios, so one will work best given 1920x1080, the other 1920x1200.  Might be possible to letterbox it at 1080 tall, if you wanted equal y # pixels.

Answer (score 0):

An image will be displayed by a viewer within the monitor's resolution.

Under normal usage, it won't be squished on one dimension, just scaled on all dimensions
so as to fit while conserving the aspect ratio. It should all be automatic
in most cases (but not all).

If you are having problems with this, please let us know your setup and especially
your operating system and video adapter and a description of the problem.

Comment: There's no issue per say; just kind of an odd thought that came; maybe i'm thinking of this wrong. Because as you mentioned scaled, mabye the system, win x, is just up-sample or down-sampling to show the same scale.

Comment: The system is a large word, but generally, as the resolutions of the two monitors are not very different, programs will adapt. You might only rarely see differences when moving a window from one to the other, but those will be minor.

Answer (score 0):

They are both marketed as "24 inch" monitors, but if you measure corner to corner diagonally (which is the measurement used to determine screen size) you will probably find that one is slightly shorter than 24 inches, and the other is slightly longer than 24 inches.

You also mentioned that you can tell that the Dell is "shorter". That is because it has a 16:9 aspect ratio. Compared to the 16:10 ratio of the HP monitor, it will look wider and shorter. That extra 1 on the 16:10 aspect ratio is where it fits in the additional 120 pixels on the vertical resolution.

The official HP website describes their monitor as having a 61cm (24 inch) diagonal display, where as the Dell is described as having a 60.97cm (24 inch) diagonal display size.

At the end of the day, it's easier to just say that a monitor that is 24 inches instead of 24.0157 inches, right?

More technical details:

The reason the image scale look the same across both monitors, even though they have different shapes, sizes, and resolutions is that the [pixel pitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_pitch) is almost identical between the two monitors.

- HP: 0.27mm Pixel Pitch
- Dell: 0.277mm Pixel Pitch

This means that the because the horizontal resolution on each monitor is the same (1920px) the pixels are going to be almost exactly the same size and therefore both reproduce images at the same physical size.

Comment: Actually, I did measure both and they were both 24 diagonally, maybe off by 1 or 2 mm only as the spec sheet said. But i guess digesting what you said about pixel pitch that does make sense in that in because the HP has a denser pixel i would have the same 1080x even though the width is physically narrower.